# Not able to install python-binance on pycharm Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, failed-installation, binance

Installation of Twisted==17.9.0 fails on Python 3.7.3. Also can't install Cryptography==2.1.4

Want to install necessary modules on Pycharm for python-binance

I've tried using the anaconda version of python but with that I still get the install error with cryptography.

```
C:\Users\Laptop\PycharmProjects\Python Trading2\venv\Scripts>pip install Twisted==17.9.0

Collecting hyperlink>=17.1.1 (from Twisted==17.9.0)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/91/e916ca10a2de1cb7101a9b24da546fb90ee14629e23160086cf3361c4fb8/hyperlink-19.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages (from zope.interface>=4.0.2->Twisted==17.9.0) (39.0.1)
Collecting attrs>=16.1.0 (from Automat>=0.3.0->Twisted==17.9.0)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/96/d828354fa2dbdf216eaa7b7de0db692f12c234f7ef888cc14980ef40d1d2/attrs-19.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages (from Automat>=0.3.0->Twisted==17.9.0) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.5 in c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages (from hyperlink>=17.1.1->Twisted==17.9.0) (2.8)
Installing collected packages: zope.interface, constantly, incremental, attrs, Automat, hyperlink, Twisted
  Running setup.py install for Twisted ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\program files\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-x06wgdqo\\Twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-jhd2kvhg\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\twisted
    copying src\twisted\copyright.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\twisted
    copying src\twisted\plugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\twisted
    copying src
```

And on and on in red.

Answer (score 0):

Today I encountered the same problem Tried everything. Then everything made sense.

1. Install VSC build tools:

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/136595/error-microsoft-visual-c-140-or-greater-is-require.html
2. Download [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted) (if you get .whl error)(file name "Twisted-20.3.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl" ). install it using CMD location/filename.
3. Install through cmd:

   ```
   pip Install Scrapy
   ```